# How to insert an image above :toc: left of asciidoc multipage?

Tags: image, tableofcontents, asciidoc, multipage

I need to put an image above the toc at the left.

I'm using multidoctor-multipage to create a html multipage manual. I need to place a logo image above the Table of Content at the left, in order that it appears at all pages.

It is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you mean `asciidoctor-multipage`? I can't find a tool named `multidoctor-multipage`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `asciidoctor-multipage` here's an approach that should work.

The default theme for Asciidoctor doesn't have any built-in feature for branding the output. It does have a feature called [Docinfo files](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/docinfo/) that lets you embed custom CSS and JavaScript into every generated page.

The Docinfo files feature can be used to achieve your goal. Using JavaScript, an image can be added to the HTML wherever you want, and CSS styles can control the image presentation.

In the same folder as your AsciiDoc document, create the file `docinfo.html` with the following content:

```html
<style>
#toc img.logo {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
</style>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    var image = document.createElement('img')
    image.setAttribute('src', 'logo.svg')
    image.setAttribute('alt', 'Logo')
    image.classList.add('logo')
    var toc = document.querySelector('#toc')
    if (toc) {
      toc.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', image)
    }
  });
</script>
```

In your AsciiDoc file, just before the `:toc: left` attribute definition, add this line:

```
:docinfo: shared
```

Then, when you generate the HTML files with `asciidoctor-multipage`, the image gets loaded and positioned above the table of contents.

Notes:

- You have to copy the image into the same folder containing the HTML, or you'll see a broken image in your browser.
- You'll need to change `logo.svg` to whatever image filename you want to use.